# for each element of a class, check the contents to see if it contains a string, and then update only that element if it does

Tags: javascript, jquery

Code version 1:

```
        var one = "one";
        $.each($(".Buttons"),(function() {
            if ($("this:contains(one)")) {
                $(this).addClass( "currentButton" ); 
            };
        }));
```

Code version 2:

```
        var one = "one";
        $(".Buttons").each(function(a, e) {
            if ($("e:contains(one)"))
            { $(e).addClass( "currentButton" ); };
        });
```

I think you see what I'm trying to do. My problem is only updating the specific element where the text is matched, but all elements are updated when only one matches.

Edit: HTML below:

```
<input type="submit" class="Buttons" value="one">
<input type="submit" class="Buttons" value="two">
<input type="submit" class="Buttons" value="one & two">
```

I am using inputs as they are programmatically added buttons using asp.net/c#

I have attempted a couple of solutions and I'm still having every element have the class added.

I updated [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fNUqG/1/) with inputs and now it's not being affected at all. I'm guessing `:contains` won't check `input` `value`.

Using my original method I fixed it as follows, or alternatively see the answer from Elias:

```
        $(".Buttons").each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr("value") == one) {
                $(this).addClass("currentButton");
            };
        });
```

Comment: @DevlshOne `e:contains('"+one+"')`

Comment: Both `"e:contains(one)"` and `"this:contains(one)"` aren't evaluating your `var one` variable correctly.  Since both of those values are in quotes, it is evaluating those as string literals.

Comment: Check my answer: `if ($("e:contains(one)"))` or `if ($("this:contains(one)"))` will _always_ be true, because `$('string-constant')` will always return an jQuery object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you're doing is a one-liner, though:

```
var one = "one";
$(".Buttons").filter(":contains('"+one+"')").addClass("currentButton");
//or
$(".Buttons").filter(":contains('one')").addClass("currentButton");
```

### [check fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fNUqG/)

This does imply your `:contains` selector is a constant value, if you need it to change according to somethign else, wrap it in a function:

```
function changeClass(contains)
{
    contains = contains || 'one';//default value
    $('.Buttons').filter(":contains('"+contains+"')").addClass('currentButton');
}
```

Of course, as always, you can change everything to parameters so this function is more likely to be reusable:

```
function changeClass(selector, filter, newClass)
{
    $(selector).filter(filter).addClass(newClass);
}
changeClass('.Buttons', ':contains("one")', 'currentButton');
```

Your problems were being caused by enclosing either `this` or `e` inside the string delimiters, which effectively turned them into string constants, not references to the DOM nodes you were trying to change
What happened is that both:

```
if ($("e:contains(one)"))
{
    $(e).addClass( "currentButton" );
}
```

and

```
if ($("this:contains(one)"))
{
    $(this).addClass( "currentButton" );
}
```

evaluated to :

```
if ([])
{
    $(this).addClass('currentButton');
}
```

In other words: you were passing *string constants* to the main jQuery function (`$()`) which probably tried to make the bet of things, and likely treated them as selectors. Sadly, they came up empty, so an empty array-like jQuery object was returned, and any object/array is a truthy value in JS, so the expressions checked evalueted to `true`, hence, nodes classes were changed.
You could just as well have written:

```
if ($('foobar, see if it matters what I write here'))
{
    console.log('It doesn\'t');
}
```

And it'll log `It doesn't` time and time again.

**Edit**

In response to your comment, if what you actually want is to filter, based on the elements' value attribute:

```
$('.Buttons').filter(function()
{//this function will be applied to each element returned by the $('.Buttons') selector
 //only those for which this callback returns true will get the currentButton class
    return /\bone\b/i.test($(this).val());
    //or, equally valid:
    return ($(this).val().indexOf('one') !== -1);
}).addClass('currentButton');
```

Note that `/\bone\b/i` will accept *"ONe"* as well as *"One"* or *"one"*, but won't return true if the value attribute contains *"bones"*, whereas `indexOf` is CaseSensitive, but doesn't check if *one* is part of a word or not.
for a case sensitive regex, you can use `/\bone\b/`, without the `i`.

A more strict, but lot shorter version of the same thing could be:

```
$('.Buttons[value~="'+one+'"]').addClass("currentButton");
```

But there are so many jQ selectors that you can use, best [keep a reference close to your chest](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: I agree. the use of the `.Buttons` selector already supplies the entire nodelist(array) of buttons, there's no need for the iteration with `.each()`, only the `.filter()`.

Comment: Check my update to [the jsfiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/fNUqG/1/). I simply changed the buttons to submit inputs and it's stopped applying the new class. Does contains not check values of inputs?

Comment: @dudledok: That's because you're using tags that don't _contain_ text, instead you have to get their value, and check that. Just pass a callback to the `filter` function: [like I did here](http://jsfiddle.net/fNUqG/2/)

Comment: @dudledok: But all in all, in that case wouldn't [this be the best approach](http://jsfiddle.net/fNUqG/3/)? `$('.Buttons[value~="'+one+'"').addClass('currentButton')`?

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vhGzY/)

Using is():

```
var one = "one";
$(".Buttons").each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":contains('"+one+"')")) {
        $(this).addClass("currentButton");
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty simply without an each function.  jQuery selectors will do the filtering for you, and then you update every element that matched the selector.

```
var text = "text to test for";

$(".Buttons:contains(" + text + ")").addclass("currentButton");
```

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R9dwX/) to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

`$("e:contains(one)")` here one is being considered as a string literal.

try like, `"e:contains('"+one+"')"` now one will be evaluated to your string.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var one = "one";
    $(".Buttons").filter(function () {
        return $(":contains('"+one+"')",this);
    }).addClass("currentButton");
```

**or**

```
    var one = "one";
    $(".Buttons").filter(function () {
        return this.innerHTML == 'one'; // note: innerHTML may be deprecated soon, avoid it
    }).addClass("currentButton");
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/uEB68/)